# kernel dies after @property in python

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am running the following code in Jupyter:

```
from typing import List

class dummy:
    def __init__(self, dum: List =[]):
        self.dum = dum

    @property
    def dum(self) -> List:
        return self.dum

    @dum.setter
    def dum(self, value: List) -> None:
        self.dum = value
```

When I run the following:

```
dummy(dum=[1,2,3])
```

The kernel dies without telling me much about the possible error. What is going on?

Comment: You shouldn't name your methods and attribute of a class the same name. `dum` is at the same time a method and an attribute, so `dummy().dum` is confusing. Renaming the attribute should solve the issue.

Comment: Did the kernel dying tell you anything at all? If so, it would be helpful to post. Future searchers would more likely find this question with it in there.

Comment: It can be useful to run failing scripts from the command line to see what happens. Here you'd get `self.dum = value`, `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
@property
def dum(self) -> List:
    return self.dum
```

This creates an infinite recursion.

- The attribute itself should have a different name. As per convention, it is usually the name of the property prefixed with an underscore.
- While we are at it, [default mutable arguments should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).
- `mypy` does not like implicit `Optional` annotations, so `List = None` should be `Optional[List] = None`.

```py
from typing import List, Optional

class dummy:
    def __init__(self, dum: Optional[List] = None):
        self.dum = dum if dum is not None else []

    @property
    def dum(self) -> List:
        return self._dum

    @dum.setter
    def dum(self, value: List) -> None:
        self._dum = value
```

Comment: It's still OK to use the property in `__init__`, rather than working with `._dum` directly. (The `_num` attribute is, in some sense, an implementation detail of the *property*, not `dummy`.) It's also arguably better to still check if `dum is None`. A caller might have reason to pass an explicit empty list as an argument without wanting `__init__` to replace it with a *new* empty list.

Comment: @chepner totally agree, thanks